# Need help simplifying javascript for loop's

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am making some kind of random image generator which displays images up onto 8 different rows (max 8 * 30 = 240) random images.

I am using the exact same for loop to output those images, 8 times over and over again:

```
var indents = [];
for (var q=0; q < 30; q++) {
    var rdmNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1;
    var imgName = "img_" + rdmNumber +".png";
    var src = "img" + "/" + imgName;
    indents.push(<div className="item-picture" key={q}><img src= {src}className="item-img" alt="Your possible winnings" /></div>);
}

var indents2 = [];
for (var w=0; w < 30; w++) {
    var rdmNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1;
    var imgName2 = "img_" + rdmNumber2 +".png";
    var src2 = "img" + "/" + imgName2;
    indents2.push(<div className="item-picture" key={w}><img src= {src2}className="item-img" alt="Your possible winnings" /></div>);
}
```

etc. etc.

Is there a nice and easy way for me to make this all into one function? It's important that the images on max. all 8 rows are in a different order, that's why I made it like this.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Well _nest_ two loops? The outer one running 8 times …

Comment: better for codereview SE IMO

Comment: all those variables only live inside the loop, you don't need to duplicate them. At that point, you just need one loop that runs 60 times, since the instructions inside the two loops are basically the same

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca But will the images be different for all the rows? They need to run at the same time, with different images.

Comment: you're randomizing them anyway, so why not?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca And how would I achieve that? (Sorry, I'm a newbie with JavaScript).

Comment: it's already there. unless you made a mistake when posting your code and you actually meant  `indents2.push` in the last line of the second loop you just need to remove the second loop and put a 60 as the exit condition for the other.

Comment: I meant idents2.push, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ok then just do as I previously suggested and at the end something like `q >= 30 ? intents.push(...) : indents2.push(...)` substituting `<div className="item-picture" key={q}><img src= {src}className="item-img" alt="Your possible winnings" /></div>` for `...`. Also, remember to quote `<div...` etc. Also `q` and `w` are weird choices for looping variables (not that it matters, but still...)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca And how would that work with 8 loops?

Comment: sorry, I missed that part of the question. in that case something like move the loop to a function and invoke it passing in the array you want to push to. then, at the last line of the function, push to the array you passed in.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca This would work perfectly, although I forgot to mention the amount of rows can vary between 3-8. The number of the row is specified by i ({i}). But I is only being given inside of the render function, where I can't put my JS because I don't want it to update on changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgs = 8;
var indents = [];
for (var i = 0; i < imgs; i++) {
    for (var q = 0; q < 30; q++) {
        //Generate image based on i and q variable for unique image
        //push image to indents
    }
}
```

You could probably just do as CBroe suggests and use 2 loops. Then use the outher loop variable and inner loop variable to generate some unique number if that is enough.

You could even split it up into 3 functions which is probably nicer (but you should attempt that yourself :)

getImage (gets a single image based on a number)

getImagesForRow (gets images for a row and returns an array)

getAllImages (would basically be the code I wrote above)

Comment: This would work perfectly, although I forgot to mention the amount of rows can vary between 3-8. The number of the row is specified by i ({i}). But I is only being given inside of the render function, where I can't put my JS because I don't want it to update on changes.

Comment: There's a lot of implicit knowledge in what you write, eg. 
render function of what?
what language is '({i})'?
what do you mean by update on change? is it code that runs on html page load ?


You could make the code into a function that takes one parameter (numberOfRows) and exchange the imgs variable with that code.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I am using ReactJS. {i} is the JSX version of the Javascript variable i. I gets defined inside of my render() variable, which displays code (I don't know if you are familiar with React.JS). Every time the page updates, the content inside render() reruns. As the page updates several times, I can't put my code inside the render() component, as the images would change several times on a page load.

Comment: Not a lot, but I would assume that you could at least set some sort of boolean variable to indicate if images has been set and if so, not resetting them (to only call the function once). This is not best practice though, there should be some other way to do it in ReactJS. Anyway the Javascript part should work, now you just need to figure out how to attach it to ReactJS.